# Class_Weight in Random Forest Python

Tags: python, random-forest, roc

I am currently trying to vary the threshold of a Random Forest Classifier in order to plot a ROC Curve. I was under the impression that the only way to do this for a Random Forest is through the use of the class_weight parameter. I have been able to do this successfully, increasing and decreasing precision, recall, true positive and false positive rates; however, I am not sure what I am actually doing. Currently I have the following;

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, oob_score=True,  n_estimators=50,max_depth=40,min_samples_split=100,min_samples_leaf=80, class_weight={0:.4, 1:.9})
```

What is the .4 and .9 actually referring too. I thought it was 40% of data set is 0's and 90% 1's however, this obviously makes no sense (over %100). What is it actually doing? THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class weights typically do not need to normalise to 1 (it's only the ratio of the class weights that is important, so demanding that they sum to 1 would not actually be a restriction though).

So setting the class weights to 0.4 and 0.9 is equivalent to assuming a split of class labels in the data of 0.4 / (0.4+0.9) to 0.9 / (0.4+0.9) [roughly ~30% belonging to class 0 and ~70% belonging to class 1].

An alternative way to view differing class weights is as a way of more strongly penalising mistakes in one class compared to another, but still assuming balanced numbers of labelings in the data. In your example, it would be 9/4 times worse to misclassify a 1 as a 0 than it would be to misclassify a 0 as a 1.

Comment: What you said makes perfect sense and really helped me understand; however, my dataset is actually the opposite of what you said, so 70% 0's and 30% 1's and more importantly I would want the opposite of the second explanation i.e. 9/4 times worse to mis-classify a 0 as a 1 (as i am doing churn prediction). BUT I have done what I showed above and that gives me fantastic results, if I flip it I get HORRIBLE results. Is your explanation opposite by any chance? i.e. 70% 0's and 30% 1's?

Comment: Hello @Paul Rubenstein, Do you know what would be the setting for a weight dic of 12 classes, I mean, documentation is not so clear abou it, so the notation they mention is {0:1, 1:1} {0:1,1:5}, I don't know what do the first 0:1 represent, and how I can set a ratio between all the classes. Thanks in advance. I already posted this question in Data Science Stack Exchange if you would like to share some insight.                                                                             https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/84163/how-to-set-a-class-

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (in my experience) way to vary the discrimination threshold of any of the scikit-learn classifiers is to use the `predict_proba()` function. Rather than returning a single output class, this returns the probabilities for membership in each class (concretely what it is doing is outputting the proportion of samples in the leaf nodes reached during the classification, averaged over all trees in the random forest.) Once you have these probabilities, it is easy to implement your own final classification step by comparing the probability for each class to some threshold which you can change.

```
probs = RF.predict_proba(X)    # output dimension: [num_samples x num_classes]
for threshold in range(0,100): 
    threshold = threshold / 100.0
    classes = (probs > threshold).astype(int)
    # further analysis here as desired
```